# 1.8.3 Quartz Scheduler Not Working Properly in IBM websphere 6.1.0.41

Tags: quartz-scheduler, websphere-6.1

Quartz Scheduler-1.8.3 Seems to be not working properly in my application.This was happen 
After upgrading websphere fix-pack.Please explain why this happen and how to resolve this issue.

```
[org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-3] [DEBUG] [SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread:595] - WorkerThread is shut down.
 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-7] [DEBUG] [SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread:595] - WorkerThread is shut down.
 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-2] [DEBUG] [SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread:595] - WorkerThread is shut down.
[org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-4] [DEBUG] [SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread:595] - WorkerThread is shut down.
[org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-5] [DEBUG] [SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread:595] - WorkerThread is shut down.
[org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-6] [DEBUG] [SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread:595] - WorkerThread is shut down.
[org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-8] [DEBUG] [SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread:595] - WorkerThread is shut down.
 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] [DEBUG] [SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread:595] - WorkerThread is shut down.
 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-9] [DEBUG] [SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread:595] - WorkerThread is shut down.
 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-10] [DEBUG] [SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread:595] - WorkerThread is shut down.
    [Timer-114] [DEBUG] [UpdateChecker:56] - Checking for available updated version of Quartz...
[Timer-114] [DEBUG] [UpdateChecker:51] - Quartz version update check failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.terracotta.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the 2 last lines of your log, Quartz is trying to check for updates.
in your quartz.properties, you should set :
    org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true